# Created a maven project using quickstart using intelliJ, didn't seem to generate any dir structure?

Tags: java, maven

Which archetype was used here: http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html

It says a directory structure should have been created for you like:

```
/src/main/java/...
/src/test/....
```

I am using intelliJ, and I created a new maven project using the quickstart archetype.

The project doesn't seem to have anything other than a pom.xml file at the moment, I guess that is all the quickstart archetype comes with template wise?

I can easily create the directory structure, but was just curious what archetype would generate a folder structure as per the maven getting started link above?

I am creating a simple java library, so was looking for a suitable archetype.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you haven't configured your IntelliJ to point at a valid Maven install, it won't create the Maven structure/etc. It does not include its own maven.

Set your M2_HOME environment directory to your Maven directory. On my Linux box I ended up exporting it within the startup script. Under OS X I edited `/etc/launchd.conf` and added a `setenv M2_HOME /my/maven/dir`. Under Windows IIRC I edited the startup script. It's cool I don't have to remember.

Once you've done that, creating a Maven project from an archetype will work.

Comment: I have it setup in my .bash_profile, but your right when IntelliJ completed making the project, I did get a message to set my M2_HOME, confused why it did't pick it up (it did for my webapp archetype I created previously)