# IntelliJ can't find my M2_HOME, why is that?

Tags: java, macos, maven, intellij-idea

When I create a new Maven project, I see an error message that says:

> [FATAL_ERROR] Cannot start Maven: No valid Maven installation found. Either set the home directory in the configuration dialog or set the M2_HOME environment variable on your system.

In terminal (I'm on a Mac) if I do:

```
echo $M2

echo $M2_HOME
```

it displays the full path to my `/apache-maven-3.0.3/bin` and `/apache-maven-3.0.3` folders.

Why would IntelliJ not be able to pick this up?

Comment: Please see my [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8089213/created-a-maven-project-using-quickstart-using-intellij-didnt-seem-to-generate/8089309#8089309) to your previous question.

Comment: @Blankman, see my answer, it's exactly for your case and describes how to set environment variables on Mac so that they are accessible by all applications, not only in terminal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Environment variables set in terminal are not always visible to GUI applications:

- http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/51677
- http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/57385/17551
- http://stackoverflow.com/q/135688/104891

Comment: Link answers are not great as they can change.

Comment: @Jeff called it. The link is now gone.

Answer (score 0):

Are you on a Linux-type system?

Is the `M2_HOME` variable only set when *you* start a *terminal* session? (e.g. in a `.bashrc` or equivalent script) ?

Try starting the IDE from the command line and see if that helps.

You might just need to set that variable on a system-wide basis as the shortcut you use to start IntelliJ might not pick up your local environment vars.